# Asp net core 3.1 webapp doesn't refresh on modify razor template

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-code

i'm using visual studio code on mac osx for running a simply web app in asp net core 3.1. 
I run application with command dotnet run in visual studio code terminal.
Now, if i modify a .cshtml template and refresh my browser, modify don't show.

Why? How can i resolve?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable runtime compilation in vs code, you need to follow below steps:

1.Add a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package,run the command in the terminal

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation -v 3.1.0
```

2.Update the project's `Startup.ConfigureServices` method to include a call to `AddRazorRuntimeCompilation`.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();//for MVC

//services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();//for Razor Pages
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#runtime-compilation

Comment: @Fabio Di Giuseppe Grear.Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Is there a way to enable auto refreshing of the browser after this?